# Outputting a dictionary to file exactly as defined in variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I am wondering if there is a way to output a dictionary to a file exactly as it would be defined as a variable?

So if in code it looks like:

```
dict1 = {01: 'val1', 02: 'val2', 03: 'val3'}
```

the contents of the file would look identical?

So file contains:

```
dict1 = {01: 'val1', 02: 'val2', 03: 'val3'}
```

I've heard of `pickle` and JSON but I ideally want to be able to import them from a module, i.e.

```
from some_module import some_dict
```

Is this possible?

Comment: why are you scared of imports?

Comment: scared of imports? please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the built-in `repr(...)` function that converts objects to a string in that way that the resulting string is a valid literal with which you could recreate the object.

It calls its argument's `__repr__()` method which at least produces valid literals for the most common basic data types. It does not work for most other objects though:

```
dict1 = {1: 'val1', 2: 'val2', 3: 'val3'}
literal = repr(dict1)

print(literal)
# Output: {1: 'val1', 2: 'val2', 3: 'val3'}
```

Now you  could store that in a Python file:

```
with open("my_dict.py", "w") as f:
    print("dict2 = " + literal, file=f)
```

And this is now importable as module from other Python scripts inside the same folder:

```
import my_dict
print(my_dict.dict2[2])
# Output: val2
```

Or if you don't want to use the module name each time, import it using `from`:

```
from my_dict import dict2
print(dict2[2])
# Output: val2
```

Comment: Perfect! just what i was after @ByteCommander helpful and informative as always!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Imports are used for importing modules, not files. You will need to read and process the file in order for this to work. You can write the dict to a file with for example:

```
output = "dict1 = "+str(dict1) 
f.write(output)
```

Comment: i have done this before with a list, wasnt sure if it was possible for a dict?

Comment: Yes it is, it isn't a dict anymore when you write it to a file. It is a string representation of a dict. And you can write strings to a file, so it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve an objects name by using the `globals()` function which shows you a dictionary over the current state of the module. But this is not a good scenario, you should use serialization of your data, maybe by JSON.